# Compare 2 different times delphi

Tags: delphi

The problem here is that it is not **comparing** correctly... at the middle of the day it's working, but at the morning it is **not** **comparing** the times correctly.

```pascal
uses SysUtils;

const
  hour = 2/24;

var
  myTime : TDateTime = StrToTime('10:59:49 AM');
  townTime : TDateTime = StrToTime('11:02:10 AM');

begin
  while delay(100) do begin
    if (TimeToStr(Now) >= TimeToStr(myTime)) then begin
      print('all gucci');
      myTime := myTime + hour;
      continue;
    end;
    if (TimeToStr(Now) >= TimeToStr(townTime)) then begin
      print('all gucci');
      townTime := townTime + hour;
      continue;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why are you comparing strings. You should compare times. Of course this isn't going to work when you have 12 hour clock. Also, your hour is two hours long which is odd. Can you format your code so the indentation is readable. Can you also provide a [mcve] so that we don't need to run your program at a specific time of day. Hard code the time values that are confusing you. Also do some debugging. Look at the strings that are being compared. If you just did that you'd see why your program behaves as it does. Debugging is the biggest area of weakness in programmers today.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `StrToTime()` with string literals. That suffers from regional parsing issues. Use `EncodeTime()` instead, eg:

```
var
  myTime : TDateTime;
  townTime : TDateTime;
begin
  myTime := EncodeTime(10, 59, 49, 0);
  townTime := EncodeTime(11, 2, 10, 0);
  ...
end;
```

And don't compare times as strings. They are numerical types, so compare them directly, eg:

```
begin
  ...
  while delay(100) do begin
    if (Time >= myTime) then begin
      print('all gucci');
      myTime := myTime + hour;
      continue;
    end;
    if (Time >= townTime) then begin
      print('all gucci');
      townTime := townTime + hour;
      continue;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Or, use `CompareTime()`, eg:

```
uses
  SysUtils, DateUtils;

...

begin
  ...
  while delay(100) do begin
    if CompareTime(Time, myTime) <> LessThanValue then begin
      print('all gucci');
      myTime := myTime + hour;
      continue;
    end;
    if CompareTime(Time, townTime) <> LessThanValue then begin
      print('all gucci');
      townTime := townTime + hour;
      continue;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thank u very much mr remy ill test ur advice and ill come back.
im sorry if im not helping u read my problem but its my first post ill try to be better next time

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `var myTime : TDateTime = EncodeTime(10, 59, 49, 0);` is never valid syntax. For typed *constants* and global variables, the equals sign is accepted, but the RHS must be a constant expression, so neither `StrToInt` nor `EncodeTime` will be accepted. However, in an inline variable/constant declaration, such a non-constant expression *is* accepted. But then you need `var` and `:=` or `const` and `=` -- not `var` and `=`.